# jquery don´t accept property, cause given string and not object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, html-object

**description:**

i try to get dynamically the values of HTML-Object´s. so i´ve written a prototype function *select* on Object. It works over the console, but not in the script. A jquery property has something against it.

**the error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't assign to property "guid" on "innerText": not an object
```

**output of the related object:**

```
Object { 0: th, 1: th, 2: th, 3: th, 4: th, 5: th, length: 6, prevObject: {…} }
```

**function select on Object:**

```
Object.prototype.select = function(what)
{
    return this.map(function() {
        return this[what];
    }).get();
}
```

**the call:**

```
label.select('innerText')
```

---

is it a known bug? is there a workaround? The debugger is just relating to a point in jquery:

```
S.find.matchesSelector(re,i),n.guid||(n.guid=S.guid++)
```

*made already a workaround:*

```
function getData(data)
{
    return $(data).map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
}
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: did you try `obj[what]`? it returns obj value of property saved in what variable or undefined if not exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *never* a good idea to add properties to the `Object.prototype` object. And it's an **especially** bad idea to add them with simple assignment like that so that they're enumerable. Also, looking at the content of your `select` function, note that virtually no objects have a `map` method on them. (Arrays are the only built-in object with `map`. jQuery objects also have it.)

I strongly recommend not adding anything to `Object.prototype`.

But if you do it anyway, make what you add *non-enumerable`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "select", {
    value() {
        // ...your code here
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
});
```

That's **still not a good idea**, because it's not uncommon for libraries to have their own specialized objects, which may well have a `select` method (jQuery objects do, for instance), setting you up for conflicts. But at least if you make it non-enumerable, the property won't show up in `for-in` loops and similar.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a jQuery specific use case you can create a jQuery plugin function.

Something like:

```js
(($) => {
  // $.fn is alias for $.prototype
  $.fn.getArr = function(what) {
    return this.map((i,el) => $(el)[what]()).get();
  }
})(jQuery)

console.log($('p').getArr('text'))
console.log($('input').getArr('val'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Para 1</p>
<p>Para 2</p>
<input value="one" />
<input value="two" />
```